# MySQL Select last day of current year

Tags: mysql

Im looking for the easiest way to select/return the last month/day of the current year in the format of 2016-12-31 using MySQL. I've seen examples using Postgres and SQL Server but not MySQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be easier solutions out there, but here's an approach to this using [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) and [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12-MONTH(NOW()) MONTH));
```

This should return the last day of the current year.

Comment: Is there any way to get 31-3 date of current year in sql @TomShaw

Answer (score 12):

Here's one solution not very elegant.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-12-31')
```

Comment: you're the only one answering the question, by returning a date string and not a date.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this one:

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),"-12-31"))
```

There is no need to find the last day of the year by add or sub days.
You already know that is 31th of th december every year.
So just give to Mysql the unique real variable: **the current year**.

This return a DATE not a date formatted STRING.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last day of a month, use the `last_day` function

> MySQL LAST_DAY() returns the last day of the corresponding month for a date or datetime value. If the date or datetime value is invalid, the function returns NULL.

Alternatively, to get the last day of the year, you can do this

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Comment: That returned the last day of the previous year, 2015-12-31.

Comment: OK, what about my second solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(concat(DATE_FORMAT(sysdate(),'%Y')),'-','10','-','01') end_year;

SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL (DAY(curdate()-1)) DAY) frist_day_month;

SELECT DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL (DAY(curdate()-1)) DAY) frist_day_month;

select    TIMESTAMPADD(month,-1*timestampdiff(month
       , now()
       , '1900-10-01'
       ),'1900-01-01')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!